# Component based architectures in JS / PHP: what indicators suggest that a UI element ought to be written as an importable component?

Tags: architecture, modules, component, modularization, import

**N.B.** Several months after initially asking this question (and not coming up with any satisfactory answers) I am now learning to use `HTML Custom Elements` / `WebComponents`. It seems the same question comes up again:

> *I know I can turn **everything** in my HTML into a `Custom Element`... so what* do */ what* don't *I turn into a `Custom Element`?*

---

This is a question about best practice in data architecture when it comes to component-based systems. There are a number of "component" technologies in vanilla javascript, not least:

- Web Workers
- ES6 Modules
- Optional External JS files

Self-evidently, whenever a document *can* be architected as a single block **or** built up dynamically from separate components, there is a spectrum of architecture possibilities, ranging from:

- The single document imports no components
- The single dynamic document imports some components
- The single dynamic document imports many components
- Every part of the dynamic document is an imported component

Most system architectures will represent a position somewhere between the two poles.

But is there a **sensible rule of thumb** or **principle** which can help an information architect decide *whether* something should be a separate, self-contained, importable component or not?

How might I decide sensibly what UI elements ought (and ought not) be written as components to import?

***What indicators suggest that a UI element ought to be written as a separate, importable component?***

---

**Example:**

```
<h1>My Weather Page</h1>

<nav>Navigation Here</nav>

<p>Introductory Paragraph Here</p>

<!-- Dynamic Weather Module Here -->

<p>Paragraph explaining how to navigate / use the weather module</p>

<footer>Footer Links and Notices Here</footer>
```

Given the page architecture above, I would be most inclined to nominate the following two as components (handled by Web Workers, ES6 Modules etc.) to be imported into the page template:

- `<nav>Navigation Here</nav>`
- `<!-- Dynamic Weather Module Here -->`

and the following four as non-imported sections of the page-template:

- `<h1>My Weather Page</h1>`
- `<p>Introductory Paragraph Here</p>`
- `<p>Paragraph explaining how to navigate / use the weather module</p>`
- `<footer>Footer Links and Notices Here</footer>`

But that feels to me like an arbitrary decision. I can imagine others proposing that *any* of the sections immediately above (especially the `<footer>` if it were, to some degree, a custom, dynamic `<footer>`) might feasibly be written as separate components imported into the page template, too.

Eventually, I'm left scratching my head and wondering if there is anything on the page which *shouldn't* be a component. That said, turning everything into a component feels like going completely overboard.

Clearly the degree of componentization is a choice ultimately made by each architect...

... but are there any **sensible guidelines / rules of thumb etc.** which can help an information architect decide what ought to be an imported component and what ought not to be an imported component in an architecture which allows for componentization?

---

I can think of the following example questions:

- Does the section appear on every page? If not, probably make it an importable component.
- Is the section dynamic and does it appear *differently* on every page? If so, probably make it an importable component.

I imagine there will be other questions similar to those above, the collected answers to which may assist in deciding whether to turn a piece of code into a separate, importable component or to leave it as a non-imported section within the main template.

---

**Added:**

Having thought about this on and off for 5 days and finding myself unable to imagine a UI element for which there could not be at least a halfway-reasonable argument to turn it into an importable component, I am starting to wonder if the question isn't better, reversed:

*"What guiding indicators suggest that a UI element ought **not** be written as a separate, self-contained, importable component?"*

Comment: I may not have time for an answer. But, maybe start with considering why you want "separate, self contained, importable components" to begin with. *How does component-izing some stuff on a page make your team's job easier?*

Comment: Thanks, @svidgen. I am building a _Content Development Environment_ so, in a wider context, a component here represents a user-generated "plug-in" which may (or may not) be reused on different pages by the same site, or by other sites. The most immediately apparent benefits of such component-ization are **plug-and-play reuse** across different documents, sites & web-apps _and_ **component-level scoping**, such that an individual developer might work on a given component without needing to know anything else about the overarching site(s) the component will be "plugging into".

Comment: A good place to start your guidelines, IMO, is just be to restate that *as guidelines*. Maybe, "If what you're developing may be re-used or benefit from it's own scoping, component-ize it." ... Bear in mind, [it still requires experience](https://fragiledeveloper.com/2019/06/09/the-principle-of-applying-principles-(POAP).html) to recognize when things are likely reusable, benefit from internal scoping, or *whatever other guiding quality* you come up with. Maybe also consider what the with problems with "over-componentization" are and state as counterbalancing guidance.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, I am seeking to avoid over-componentizing my setup. This is the main thrust of my question above: while I know I _can_ turn every last nut and bolt into a component, I feel this is going overboard and I want to establish if there are any rules of thumb I can refer to, to help me decide when to turn something into a component and when not to.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to thinking about this I have come up with is to ask the following **two questions**:

1) Does the UI Element represent an **enhancement** to the document? (ie. would the document remain functional and convey a sense of *"being complete"* even *without the component*?)

2) Even where the UI Element *is* a **core part** of the document (and not an enhancement), is the component, nevertheless, editorially highly dynamic, displaying different (sometimes substantially different) content from one document to the next? (Like a section-specific contextual menu etc.)

Where either condition above is **TRUE**, it is *probably* a better architectural decision to write the UI Element as an importable component.

I recognise that this isn't perfect, but it's the best I have been able to come up with so far.